# How do you wrap an object on a grid in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

I'm currently working on a Mars Rover Kata.  I've created a 10x10 grid that the rover can move forwards and backwards and change directions ['N', 'E', 'S', 'W'].  Because the grid actually represents a spherical planet, the rover should wrap on the 10x10 grid instead of going off completely.  I'm trying to code the wrapping.  Object included for more context.  I'm currently using if/else statements to determine the cases in which the rover should wrap, but I know that I am overcomplicating it.  Would a switch statement be more efficient?  Or can I use a loop somehow?  I'm new to Javascript.  Thanks so much.

```
var myRover = {
  position: [[0],[0]],
  direction: 'N',
  roverDirections = ['N', 'E', 'S', 'W'],
  marsGrid: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
  obstacles: [];
};

if (command === 'f') {

if ((myRover.position[[0],[0]]) && (myRover.direction === 'S')) {
  myRover.position[[10],[0]];
}

else if ((myRover.position[[0],[0]]) && (myRover.direction === 'W')) {
  myRover.position[[0],[10]];
}

if ((myRover.position[[0],[10]]) && (myRover.direction === 'E')) {
  myRover.position[[0],[0]];
}

else if ((myRover.position[[0],[10]]) && (myRover.direction === 'S')) {
  myRover.position[[10],[10]];
}

if ((myRover.position[[10],[0]]) && (myRover.direction === 'N')) {
  myRover.position[[0],[0]];
}

else if ((myRover.position[[10],[0]]) && (myRover.direction === 'W')) {
  myRover.position[[10],[10]];
}

if ((myRover.position[[10],[10]]) && (myRover.direction === 'N')) {
  myRover.position[[0],[10]];
}

else if ((myRover.position[[0],[0]]) && (myRover.direction === 'E')) {
  myRover.position[[10],[0]];
}


}
```

Comment: There is probably more code incrementing and decrementing a counter on where they are going correct? If so, you can have something that makes `counter = 0` if the number is `> 10` or `counter = 10` if number is `< 0`

Comment: You’ve got some syntax errors: `roverDirections =` should be `roverDirections:`, remove the `;` after `obstacles`, also `myRover.position[[0],[0]]` doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: You could define a gridPoint Object, with "pointers" to the surrounding gridPoints, this way you can easily connect the edges. so as you move around, you change currentGridPoint of the rover, instead of x,y coords

Comment: you could simplify your position with just a one dimensional array, like `[1, 5]`.

Comment: Just a side note, your cases for moving N/S aren't accurate to a spherical planet representation.  You'd want to keep the Y position, shift the X position by half your maximum value, and invert your direction.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object for calculating the new position of the rover with a given direction.

```
directions = {
    N: [0, 9], // 9 because length of x - 1 and the positive remainder operator
    W: [9, 0], // 9 because length of y - 1
    O: [1, 0],
    S: [0, 1]
};
```

Then you could determine the new position with

```
direction = 'S';
newPos = [
    (oldPos[0] + directions[direction][0]) % 10,
    (oldPos[1] + directions[direction][1]) % 10
];
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.Would there be any way to do this with a for loop or a while loop as well?

Comment: it depends if you like to change more than one position, you clould wrap the above in a loop of your choice.